# This JQuery function only fires once. What's wrong?

Tags: jquery, function, triggers

I'm trying to trigger content to pop up when a title is clicked. Here is the function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            $(".event-info").hide(); // make sure all content in event-info class is hidden

            $(".event-title").click(function(){
        // find the .event-info within the same div as .event-title is and slide to         show
            $(".event-info").hide();    $(this).parent().children(".event-        info").toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, 500);           })

    });
    </script>
```

My problem is when it runs, it only runs once! I click on the title, the content pops up, I click it again and it closes. But if I want to click it a third time to pop up the content it doesn't work. So what i'm asking is, what should be added/removed from this function to make it so I can pop up the content as much as I want?

Thanks!

---

UPDATE!

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<div class="event-title"> Title that triggers content to appear is here </div>

<div class="event-info"> Content that appears is placed here</div>
</html>
```

***UPDATE

Ok, so Aiias helped me get it so I can open/close the content to infinity and beyond wit this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".event-info").hide();
  $(".event-title").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".event-info").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

EVERYTHING IS WORKING! THANKS GUYS! GREAT HELP!

Comment: What does the HTML look like and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Hey Aiias! I just posted the HTML. It's pretty straight-forward.

Comment: try removing `$(".event-info").hide();` from your click event callback function

Comment: Alright! But where should I place it then? I inserted that to make the content disappear when another title is clicked to display different content. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: you already made them hide on document ready

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? My answer should be compatible with all jQuery versions as [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) has been around since `jQuery 1.0`.

Comment: @user2457773 - Comment on **Update**: Can you show us the HTML code that shows how you are formatting multiple sets of `event-info` and `event-title` elements?

Comment: Everything seems to be working now Aiias! Thanks! Do you have an idea on how I can get the closing content (when i click another title and new content pops up) to slide up and close instead of just abruptly dissapearing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to hide the `.event-info` within the click handler since toggle handles this. Try using jQuery's [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/):

**Updated**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".event-info").hide();
  $(".event-title").click(function() {
    var eventInfo = $(this).parent().children(".event-info");
    $('.event-info').not(eventInfo).slideUp();
    eventInfo.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

See this working **updated** jsFiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/9meXY/1/

Comment: @user2457773 - No problem, happy to help. Click the checkmark under the voting spot at the top left of my answer to mark this as answered.

Comment: One more thing though: How would I make it that only one content can be showed at once? So if someone clicks on another title, then the one opened closes before the new one opens?

Comment: @user2457773 - How are the other `titles` and `infos` formatted? If you enclose each pair of `title` and `info` within a plain `<div>` then all you need to do is add `$(".event-info").hide();` in the click handler before the `slideToggle()`.

Comment: That did it! Is there a way to make the closing content close slidding up? Sorry man i'm a total noob lol Thanks guys your saving my life right now haha

Comment: @user2457773 - See my updated answer and jsFiddle for hiding other `event-info`s when a different `event-title` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(".event-info").hide(); // make sure all content in event-info class is hidden

    $(".event-title").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".event-info").toggle({
            easing: "slide", 
            direction: "up", 
            duration: 500
        });           
    })

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/APkxU/)

Update:

```
$(".event-title").click(function(){
    val el = $(this).siblings(".event-info").toggle({
        easing: "slide", 
        direction: "up", 
        duration: 500
    });
    (".event-info").not(el).hide();
})
```

Comment: Hey Arun! I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. On pageload the content isn't hidden and the trigger doesn't do anything...weird. Thanks though! It's appreciated :P

Comment: but the fiddle seems to be working!!! again do you have jquery ui added because the easing `slide` required ui project

Comment: Also can you modify the fiddle to recreate the problems

Comment: this should work thought. It's fully working on fiddle. Maybe it's not the Jquery, or something else is stopping the JQuery from working. I have the Jquery in my footer, along with some other Jquery functions for other things.

Comment: It seems to be working now guys. Thanks for all the help! This community has a record breaking response time...jesus haha

Comment: One more thing though: How would I make it that only one content can be showed at once? So if someone clicks on another title, then the one opened closes before the new one opens?